# No required module provides package after running go get

Tags: go, github, import

So I have a GOPATH set to my working directory and I create a new script file.go. In that script I use I `import "github.com/..."` I ran 'go get github.com/... and it appeared to download but when running `go run file.go` I still get: `no required module provides package github.com/gordonklaus/portaudio: go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory; see 'go help modules'`.

I tried adding `go.mod` but then the error just changes to:

```
go: no module declaration in go.mod. To specify the module path:
        go mod edit -module=example.com/mod
```

So I adding the following to my `go.mod` file and it looks like this now:

```
module MyModuleName

go 1.17

require(
    "github.com/..." v1.2.3
)
```

But I get:

```
missing go.sum entry for module providing package github.com/...; to add:
        go mod download github.com/...
```

But when I run `go mod download github.com/...` I get:

```
github.com/...@v1.2.3: invalid version: unknown revision v1.2.3
```

So I don't know what todo from here.

Comment: The go.mod file does not have a module declaration.  Edit the file to add the declaration, possibly by using the command shown in the error message.  [How to write Go code](https://go.dev/doc/code) is a good tutorial on the subject.

Comment: Yeah thanks and sorry for the slow reply. I did in fact add a module declaration and a require statement to my go.mod file. I'm still getting stuck on not knowing what I'm supposed to use for a version number...

Comment: Use `go get github.com/gordonklaus/portaudio` to add the require statement to the go.mod file.  The `go get` command will fill in a version.

Answer (score 1):

I would:

- edit `go.mod` and remove the line where v1.2.3 is
- `go get github.com/gordonklaus/portaudi` (executed in the project folder, where `go.mod` is)
- `go mod tidy`

The end result should be the library added with a tag matching its latest release.

Comment: When I run `go get github.com/gordonklaus/portaudio` I get  `# pkg-config --cflags  -- portaudio-2.0 pkg-config: exec: "pkg-config": executable file not found in %PATH%`

Comment: @kpie Indeed. I suspect https://github.com/gordonklaus/portaudio/issues/47#issuecomment-932158353 or https://github.com/gordonklaus/portaudio/issues/7#issuecomment-198653383.

Answer (score 0):

If someone having similar error:

```
go: no module declaration in go.mod. To specify the module path:
    go mod edit -module=example.com/mod
```

while trying to run some go code like `go run test.go`, the following helped me to eliminate the error:

```
GO111MODULE=on go run test.go
```

After that I was able to run go code normally, without specifying `GO111MODULE` variable.